# How can I perform 3D array calculations efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I will be glad for your help.

I have a 3d array in python (500,200,1000), 500 rows, 200 columns over 1000 frames.
What is the most efficient way to calculate per coordinate over all the 1000 frames the percentage of incidents of a specific value?

for example, the input is a 3d matrix with Value=1.
I need to find the percentage of occurrences of the values above 1, per pixel in the frame, over all the frames. The output is a 2d array that each element represents the percentage [100*(values above 1)(all values i,j over the frames)].

[image].

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
thresh = 1
(array > thresh).mean(axis=-1)
```

Running on sample data:

```
np.random.seed(1)
array = np.random.rand(3,4,1000)
thresh = 0.3

(array > thresh).mean(axis=-1)
```

gives you:

```
array([[0.704, 0.708, 0.681, 0.694],
       [0.702, 0.717, 0.687, 0.683],
       [0.659, 0.701, 0.727, 0.697]])
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the replay! already very helpful! But, how from this i can get the percentage? it's calculating the mean over the samples, right?

Comment: @SashaVasserfirer that's the percentage in scale `0,1`. So  in the sample, you have approximately 70% of values `>0.3`, which is reasonable from the distribution of the sample.

Comment: OK great!! now I see in my code that it's working!
but can you please explain in less "pythonic" language this method? 
I don't understand how it works :)